# Href not working despite CSP and <allow-intent>

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build, content-security-policy

I have made an app using PhoneGap (so I am writing in HTML, JavaScript and CSS) and in this app I've written multiple "href" functions such as these:

```
<a href="mailto:marcel.loman@apt-alu-products.com">
marcel.loman@apt-alu-products.com </a><br />

Website: <a href="http://www.apt-alu-products.com">www.apt-alu-products.com</a></p>
```

I have added some "Content-security-policy lines in the "head" part of all of my HTML documents to ensure the fact it would work if I run the apk on android. This CSP looks lik this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
         content="default-src *; 
                  style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                  script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

On top of that I've added the following lines in my config.xml file in between the "widget" part:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

(I know these lines aren't recommended due to security reasons, but these were my last resort) 
Despite of al these lines the links still don't work when I build an APK out of it and run it on my Android phone.

There are lots of articles on the internet about this subject, but none of the ones i read were able to tackle my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these links directly into the app's HTML without the [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) plugin will not work. The `http` link will actually load the content into your Webview, replacing your app code.

I assume you want the `mailto` link to launch the default mail client and the `http` link to open in the system browser? Assuming this, do the following:

First, add the inappbrowser plugin to your project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

Then add some code to use the inappbrowser plugin to open the link with `window.open` rather than the default behaviour of opening the link within the Webview.(The following uses jQuery):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=http], a[href^=mailto]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent Webview from following link
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_system'); // Open with inappbrowser
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i indeed had to download a plugin. I've never done this so it took some further research. However I've chosen to install the [cordova-plugin-whitelist] (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)  because I would not have to use the query part. This works fine as well.